# Accepting paypal payments on a New Zealand Shopping Cart site

Tags: paypal

I am developing a site in New Zealand with a shopping cart. I am trying to find a good payment gateway. I tried paypal website payments standart but then realised that paypal does not offer this service in New Zealand, though i didn't see this info on their site and only found out when i was playing around in sandbox. My question is which payment gateways are available to developers in New Zealand. Does paypal offer something that i could use, where do i find info on paypal about which countries their services are offered in?
I would especially like to hear from developers in NZ about what you have used. 
Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok my bad, it turns out that paypal does offer this service in New Zealand. Just when you are in the sandbox, don't try and create a buyer or user account automatically because then it does not give you all the country options. Instead create the test seller and buyer accounts manually because then you are given a complete set of countries.